# XFCE/LightDM: Tearing-Fix vs. No Desktop After Logging in

Tags: x11, login, xfce, lightdm, lightdm-gtk-greeter

I have Manjaro/XFCE/LightDM and a GeForce GT 710 and I followed [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Avoid_screen_tearing) to get rid of tearing. I added those three lines to my X-configuration. After I log in in the greeter the screen only shows the background image and the mouse cursor. After I press Ctrl+Alt+F2 and Ctrl+Alt+F7 I can see the desktop and the applications that auto-start. Without the three lines desktop and applications are visible right away.

Yes, I googled.

My X-configurations:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf:

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.26  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-01)  Thu Dec  8 19:07:46 PST 2016
Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier  "Layout0"
  Screen   0  "Screen0"
  InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
  InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
Section "Files"
EndSection
Section "InputDevice"
  # generated from default
  Identifier "Mouse0"
  Driver     "mouse"
  Option     "Protocol" "auto"
  Option     "Device" "/dev/psaux"
  Option     "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
  Option     "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
Section "InputDevice"
  # generated from default
  Identifier "Keyboard0"
  Driver     "kbd"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "Monitor0"
  VendorName  "Unknown"
  ModelName   "Unknown"
  HorizSync    28.0 - 33.0
  VertRefresh  43.0 - 72.0
  Option      "DPMS"
EndSection
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Device0"
  Driver     "nvidia"
  VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
 Option      "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
  Identifier  "Screen0"
  Device      "Device0"
  Monitor     "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection  "Display"
      Depth    24
  EndSubSection
EndSection

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf

# Read and parsed by systemd-localed. It's probably wise not to edit this file
# manually too freely.
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "system-keyboard"
  MatchIsKeyboard "on"
  Option "XkbLayout" "de"
  Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
  Option "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mhwd.conf

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 375.26  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-01)  Thu Dec  8 19:07:46 PST 2016
Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier  "Layout0"
  Screen   0  "Screen0"
  InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
  InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection
Section "Files"
EndSection
Section "InputDevice"
  # generated from default
  Identifier "Mouse0"
  Driver     "mouse"
  Option     "Protocol" "auto"
  Option     "Device" "/dev/psaux"
  Option     "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
  Option     "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
Section "InputDevice"
  # generated from default
  Identifier "Keyboard0"
  Driver     "kbd"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  VendorName "Unknown"
  ModelName  "Unknown"
  HorizSync   28.0 - 33.0
  VertRefresh 43.0 - 72.0
  Option     "DPMS"
EndSection
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Device0"
  Driver     "nvidia"
  VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
  Option     "NoLogo" "1"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
  Identifier  "Screen0"
  Device      "Device0"
  Monitor     "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection  "Display"
      Depth    24
  EndSubSection
  Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
  Option "AllowIndirectGLXProtocol" "off"
  Option "TripleBuffer" "on"
EndSection
Section "Extensions"
  Option "Composite" "Enable"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
  Identifier      "Keyboard Defaults"
  MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
  Option          "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[ 13766.904] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.1
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 13766.904] Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
[ 13766.904] Current Operating System: Linux runlikehell 4.14.66-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 22 21:45:26 UTC 2018 x86_64
[ 13766.904] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.14-x86_64 root=UUID=6ddc54eb-3d4c-4bab-b2b9-9a3e01d25a7a rw resume=UUID=3290b951-2ffd-4a02-b65c-19a4b8a9962c quiet splash
[ 13766.904] Build Date: 09 August 2018  06:37:34PM
[ 13766.904]  
[ 13766.904] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[ 13766.904]  Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
  to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 13766.904] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
  (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
  (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 13766.904] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Aug 31 17:29:08 2018
[ 13766.904] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[ 13766.904] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 13766.904] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 13766.904] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[ 13766.904] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[ 13766.904] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[ 13766.905] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[ 13766.905] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Device0"
[ 13766.905] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[ 13766.905] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[ 13766.905] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 13766.905] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 13766.905] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 13766.905] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[ 13766.905] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 13766.905] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi".
[ 13766.905]  Entry deleted from font path.
[ 13766.905]  (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi").
[ 13766.905] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi".
[ 13766.905]  Entry deleted from font path.
[ 13766.905]  (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi").
[ 13766.905] (==) FontPath set to:
  ...
[ 13766.905] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 13766.905] (WW) Ignoring unrecognized extension "Composite"
[ 13766.905] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[ 13766.905] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[ 13766.905] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[ 13766.905] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 13766.905]  X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 13766.905]  X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[ 13766.905]  X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[ 13766.905]  X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 13766.905] (++) using VT number 7

[ 13766.906] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[ 13766.906] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 13766.907] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 13766.907] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" setting /dev/dri/card0 as PrimaryGPU
[ 13766.908] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:128b:1462:8c93 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfd000000/16777216, 0xf0000000/134217728, 0xf8000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 13766.909] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[ 13766.909] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 13766.909] (II) Loading /usr/lib/nvidia/xorg/libglx.so
[ 13766.913] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[ 13766.913]  compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[ 13766.913]  Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[ 13766.913] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  396.54  Tue Aug 14 22:37:05 PDT 2018
[ 13766.913] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[ 13766.913] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[ 13766.914] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[ 13766.914]  compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[ 13766.914]  Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 13766.914] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  396.54  Tue Aug 14 22:15:03 PDT 2018
[ 13766.914] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[ 13766.940] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 13766.940] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 13766.941] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[ 13766.941] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 13766.941]  compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.0
[ 13766.941]  ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 13766.941] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[ 13766.941] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[ 13766.941] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[ 13766.941] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 13766.941]  compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.0
[ 13766.941]  ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 13766.941] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[ 13766.941] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[ 13766.941] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[ 13766.944] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 13766.944] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[ 13766.944] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 13766.944] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[ 13766.944] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" options to /dev/dri/card0
[ 13766.944] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
[ 13766.944] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[ 13767.226] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[ 13767.226] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[ 13767.226] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0 (boot)
[ 13767.226] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[ 13767.228] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GT 710 (GK208) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[ 13767.228] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[ 13767.228] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 80.28.a6.00.22
[ 13767.228] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 8X
[ 13767.230] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[ 13767.230] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 13767.230] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 13767.245] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-0): connected
[ 13767.245] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[ 13767.245] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 13767.245] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 13767.245] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[ 13767.245] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[ 13767.245] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[ 13767.245] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[ 13767.248] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[ 13767.248] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[ 13767.248] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[ 13767.248] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[ 13767.248] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[ 13767.248] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[ 13767.248] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
[ 13767.251] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (93, 94); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[ 13767.251] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[ 13767.252] (II) NVIDIA: Using 6144.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[ 13767.252] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[ 13767.254] (II) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: failed to connect to the ACPI event daemon; the daemon
[ 13767.254] (II) NVIDIA(0):     may not be running or the "AcpidSocketPath" X
[ 13767.254] (II) NVIDIA(0):     configuration option may not be set correctly.  When the
[ 13767.254] (II) NVIDIA(0):     ACPI event daemon is available, the NVIDIA X driver will
[ 13767.255] (II) NVIDIA(0):     try to use it to receive ACPI event notifications.  For
[ 13767.255] (II) NVIDIA(0):     details, please see the "ConnectToAcpid" and
[ 13767.255] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "AcpidSocketPath" X configuration options in Appendix B: X
[ 13767.255] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Config Options in the README.
[ 13767.275] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[ 13767.284] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[ 13767.284] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[ 13767.284] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse disabled
[ 13767.284] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[ 13767.285] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "PrimaryGPU" is not used
[ 13767.285] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" is not used
[ 13767.285] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[ 13767.285] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[ 13767.285] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[ 13767.285] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[ 13767.285] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[ 13767.285] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[ 13767.285] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[ 13767.285] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[ 13767.285] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[ 13767.285] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[ 13767.285] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[ 13767.286] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[ 13767.286] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[ 13767.286] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[ 13767.286] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[ 13767.286] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[ 13767.286] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[ 13767.286] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension Present
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[ 13767.287] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[ 13767.288] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension NV-GLX
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension NV-CONTROL
[ 13767.288] (II) Initializing extension XINERAMA
[ 13767.328] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[ 13767.328] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 13767.328] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[ 13767.328] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[ 13767.328] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[ 13767.328] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[ 13767.330] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 13767.330]  compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.28.0
[ 13767.330]  Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[ 13767.330]  ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[ 13767.330] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[ 13767.330] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[ 13767.330] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[ 13767.330] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 13767.330] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 13767.330] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 13767.330] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[ 13767.342] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[ 13767.342] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[ 13767.342] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 13767.342] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[ 13767.342] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[ 13767.365] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 13767.365] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 13767.365] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event3)
[ 13767.365] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 13767.365] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[ 13767.365] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[ 13767.365] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[ 13767.365] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[ 13767.365] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[ 13767.365] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 13767.366] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 13767.366] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[ 13767.366] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device removed
[ 13767.402] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/device:03/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input3/event3"
[ 13767.402] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[ 13767.402] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 13767.402] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[ 13767.402] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[ 13767.403] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 13767.403] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[ 13767.403] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[ 13767.403] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 13767.403] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[ 13767.403] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[ 13767.403] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[ 13767.403] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[ 13767.403] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[ 13767.403] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 13767.404] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 13767.404] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 13767.404] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[ 13767.422] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[ 13767.422] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[ 13767.422] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 13767.422] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[ 13767.422] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[ 13767.423] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 13767.423] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 13767.424] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event11)
[ 13767.424] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 13767.424] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 13767.424] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event10)
[ 13767.424] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 13767.424] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
... mouse ...
[ 13767.459] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 13767.459] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 13767.460] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Mic (/dev/input/event4)
[ 13767.460] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 13767.460] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 13767.460] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic (/dev/input/event5)
[ 13767.460] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 13767.460] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 13767.460] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line (/dev/input/event6)
[ 13767.460] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 13767.460] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 13767.460] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Line Out (/dev/input/event7)
[ 13767.460] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 13767.460] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 13767.460] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone (/dev/input/event8)
[ 13767.460] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 13767.460] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 13767.461] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[ 13767.461] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 13767.461] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[ 13767.461] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[ 13767.461] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[ 13767.461] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[ 13767.461] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[ 13767.461] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 13767.461] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 13767.461] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[ 13767.461] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[ 13767.478] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/event0"
[ 13767.478] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[ 13767.478] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 13767.478] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[ 13767.479] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[ 13767.480] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 13767.480] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
```

`/home/sjngm/.xsession-errors`:

```
gpg-agent[25981]: WARNUNG: "--write-env-file" ist eine veraltete Option - sie hat keine Wirkung.
gpg-agent: Ein gpg-agent läuft bereits - ein weiterer wird nicht gestartet

(xfce4-session:25974): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 17:29:12.371: gpg-agent returned no PID in the variables

(xfce4-session:25974): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 17:29:12.371: xfsm_manager_load_session: Something wrong with /home/sjngm/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-runlikehell:0, Does it exist? Permissions issue?
Warning: Unsupported high keycode 372 for name <I372> ignored
         X11 cannot support keycodes above 255.
         This warning only shows for the first high keycode.
Warning: Unsupported high keycode 372 for name <I372> ignored
         X11 cannot support keycodes above 255.
         This warning only shows for the first high keycode.

** (xfce4-clipman:25994): WARNING **: 17:29:13.061: Unable to register GApplication: Für die Schnittstelle org.gtk.Application auf /org/xfce/clipman wurde bereits ein Objekt exportiert
(xfce4-clipman:25994): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 17:29:13.061: g_application_get_is_remote: assertion 'application->priv->is_registered' failed
(xfce4-clipman:25994): GLib-WARNING **: 17:29:13.061: g_set_application_name() called multiple times
(xfwm4:25984): xfwm4-WARNING **: 17:29:13.411: Error waiting on vblank with DRI: Das Argument ist ungültig
(wrapper-2.0:26035): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:29:14.405: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
(pamac-tray:26015): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 17:29:14.420: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
(wrapper-2.0:26072): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:29:14.420: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -3 and height 30
(xfce4-clipman:25994): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 17:29:14.441: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
(wrapper-2.0:26071): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:29:14.456: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -3 and height 30
(wrapper-2.0:26078): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:29:14.531: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -3 and height 30
(wrapper-2.0:26069): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:29:14.581: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -3 and height 30
(wrapper-2.0:26076): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:29:14.592: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
(wrapper-2.0:26076): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:29:14.592: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -2 and height 29
```

`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (only the uncommented lines):

```
[LightDM]
run-directory=/run/lightdm

[Seat:*]
session-wrapper=/etc/lightdm/Xsession

[XDMCPServer]

[VNCServer]
```

`/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`:

```
[greeter]
background = /usr/share/backgrounds/maia.png
theme-name = Vertex-Maia
icon-theme-name = Vertex-Maia
font-name = Cantarell 10
xft-antialias = true
xft-hintstyle = hintfull
show-clock = false
position = 50%,center 50%,center
screensaver-timeout = 60
hide-user-image = true
```

`/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.26.0, UID=0 PID=25883
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.00s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Writing X server authority to /run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Launching X Server
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Launching process 25889: /usr/bin/X :0 -seat seat0 -auth /run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c15
[+0.60s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 25889
[+0.60s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Got signal from X server :0
[+0.60s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+0.61s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+0.61s] DEBUG: Session pid=25902: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+0.63s] DEBUG: Session pid=25902: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+0.63s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+0.63s] DEBUG: Session pid=25902: Running command /usr/bin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
[+0.63s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm
[+0.63s] DEBUG: Session pid=25902: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log
[+0.70s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+0.70s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c47
[+0.71s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c47
[+0.71s] DEBUG: Session c47 is already active
[+0.89s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.26.0 api=1 resettable=false
[+1.09s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for sjngm
[+1.09s] DEBUG: Session pid=25945: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'sjngm'
[+1.09s] DEBUG: Session pid=25945: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+1.09s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
```

I'm probably missing that one file that you need, so please let me know what you need (and also what not as I'm limited to 30k text here...).

Comment: Your `xorg.conf` has duplicate entries. Start by removing those, along with the `"Composite"` extension setting. See if that helps.

Comment: @Mioriin OK, will try, but do section names need to be unique or is it section name plus identifier?

Comment: Refer to `man xorg.conf` for specifics on how the file is structured.

Comment: @Mioriin Tried it, but didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** I found another possible solution [on the Nvidia forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1029381/linux/black-screen-at-desktop-login-gtx-750-ti-390-25-/3): Delete the file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`.

---

I have the same issue and narrowed it down to the Composition Pipeline setting. When it is enabled, the XFCE desktop does not become visible, but instead the LightDM background stays on screen. Switching between TTY forces the screen the update in a way that resolves the issue, but this is cumbersome.

If you remove the "metamodes" setting from your X configuration, the problem should resolve, but you will again have screen tearing.

What worked for me was to run the following command on session startup (you can add it in XFCE's Session and Startup settings) to force the screen to update with Composition Pipeline enabled:

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

Note that you might want to add `ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On` as well.

This is obviously a workaround and I don't know what the root cause is or how to fix it. Other display managers seem to work fine with the setting enabled.

Comment: I'm not the expert here and don't know the difference between `ForceCompositionPipeline` and `ForceFullCompositionPipeline`, but I already use the latter (see above). You might be right about it being an initialisation issue. When I use the "Nvidia X Server Settings"-app and check the ForceFullCompositionPipeline, it's all working without tearing or other issues. Is it a fact that other display managers work fine?

Comment: You have the setting in your xorg.conf file, which means it will be applied when X starts. However, based on my own experiments, this seems to be a problem for LightDM (you can test this by removing the metamodes option from your xorg.conf file). If you re-apply the setting using the `nvidia-settings` command when your XFCE session starts, it clears the screen and causes the desktop to become visible. This allows you to work around the issue while keeping the setting enabled.

In my case, I kept the setting in my xorg.conf and simply added the command to my session startup.

Comment: I do not know for a fact that another display manager will work actually. Perhaps the issue is specific to XFCE+LightDM. You can [try another display manager](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Install_Display_Managers) to see for yourself. I prefer LightDM for my own setup though.

Comment: I guess I was reading your answer too quickly and didn't get the difference to the X-conf. Thanks for pointing it out again...

Comment: I just found out that the workaround fix doesn't succeed 100% of the time. Let's hope someone finds out how to really solve this issue.

Comment: I found another possible solution [on the Nvidia forums](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1029381/linux/black-screen-at-desktop-login-gtx-750-ti-390-25-/3): Delete the file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`. Workaround is no longer needed. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Cool! I have three displays in there and commenting out two of them didn't help. Renaming the file helped :)